# Can we frame a passive construction for present/past/future perfect continuous sentences?

Tags: passive-voice

I would like to know if we can construct a sentence in present/past/future perfect continuous tense? How common are they? why many English grammar books don't mention it?

Thanks

Comment: You mean to have all those tenses in a single sentence ?

Comment: No. I want to know if we can construct passive voice structures for these tenses (perfect continuous). If yes, how common are they?

Comment: So, why you don't try a Grammar book like grammar in use series?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think the purpose of this website is to clarify your doubts by putting up questions. I can't ask a book a question.  I've referred several books, there is a contradiction among them.  :)

Comment: I will be happy to see those contradictions

Comment: Which book should I refer Cardinal ?

Comment: Cambridge Advanced Grammar in Use is fine . (written by Martin Hewings)

Comment: In my dialect, where StoneyB has "being" we'd say "getting": "By the time I retire, that damn road will have been *getting* built for sixty years...."

Comment: @TRomano What's your dialect?

Comment: @Sirius: "Central Atlantic", according to the Dictionary of Regional American English http://www.daredictionary.com/?region=C%20Atl#entriesList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passive perfects with any time reference are possible.

- That road has been being built for forty years now.
- That road had been being built for twenty years when I started driving.
- By the time I retire that road will have been being built for sixty years, and the damn thing still won't be finished.

None of them can be called unusual or particularly rare, there's just not a lot of need for them, especially the future version.

I can't say why your grammar books don't mention them—perhaps because once you get past the ordinary active versions it's not much of a trick to marry them.

Comment: Thanks StoneyB but I wanted to know about the passive construction. Example: Recently, the work has been being done by John.

Comment: @Sirius Ah, I now see that's in your title. I've fixed it.

Comment: Thank you again Stoney. Will it be correct if I say:- This project has been being worked for the last 2 years.

Comment: @Sirius You may say it has been being worked **on** for the last two years -- we don't "work" a project.